# how to concat multiple values of a single cell in sql

Tags: sql

i have a table in database like this

```
 column1      |  column2
 -------------+---------
 one two      |  three50 
 four , five  |  six30
```

I am looking for a select query who can fetch result like

```
onetwothree
forfivesix
```

Comment: Do you would like to replace blank and comma with nothing?

Comment: Replace , and SPACE using REPLACE function in SQLSERVER

Comment: Tag Whether you are using Oracle/mysql/Sybase etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Oracle:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(column1, '[ ,]+$','') 
FROM table
```

In SQL Server/MySQL/Sybase/even Oracle use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, "," , ""), " ", "")
FROM table
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer helped you then accept the answer and close it, so others can use it.

Comment: user_id  | email_id  | type 
---------------------------------------
000121  | test1234   | EXT
000125  | best_21    | LOT
000128  | lite_21@   | EXT
i want to use like

Select * from tablename where Concat (emailid,'',type) LIKE 'test1234 EXT'

Comment: please try to answer my this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163969/how-to-use-concat-columns-of-same-table-in-where-condition/27163996?noredirect=1#comment42822356_27163996

Comment: Somebody will look into it.