# how to use concat columns of same table in Where condition

Tags: sql

```
user_id  | email_id  | type 
---------------------------------------
000121  | test1234   | EXT
000125  | best_21    | LOT
000128  | lite_21@   | EXT
```

i want to use `like`

```
Select * from tablename where Concat (emailid,'',type) LIKE 'test1234 EXT'
```

but this query is not working

Comment: Are using SQL Server?

Comment: i asked the database? MYSQL or MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
Select * from tablename where emailid LIKE 'test1234' AND type LIKE ' EXT'
```

Comment: not working...the user may type either test1234 or ext or both test234ext so it shud be flexible –

Comment: Tell me, are the values 'test1234' and 'EXT' being passed as parameters to a procedure? say '@EmailID' and '@type'

Comment: no test1234 is just adn example...the user may type 'xyz@gmail.com ABC' or only 'xyz@gmail.com' or only 'abc'

Comment: so you are saying that only one value will be passed with no bifurcation, may be space or something, and this value could be in either of the columns or both at a time. if that is the case, then I guess Kumar's Solution should work for you. or you are expecting something else?

Comment: no Codeek when the user will pass the value the value could be in either column1 or column2 but not in both..

Comment: no Codeek..when the user will pass the value...the value could be in either column1 or column2 or concatination of olumn1+coulmn2....so the main problem is when user passes a value like "(column1.item + column2.item)" in which scanning of both the tables is required

Comment: even in that case, Kumar's solution should work. Did you try it? and I think in your question you have used a 'space' between text1234 and EXT. if you are using space, make sure your concatenation is using space too. so make it either : (emailid+' '+type) LIKE 'text1234 EXT' --or whatever parameter that holds the value           OR        (emailid+''+type) LIKE 'text1234EXT'

Comment: codeek give me ur email id i will send will pictures of my query

Comment: yaa i am using space when the user passes two values and i have done with kumar's solution also

Comment: post your query in sqlfiddler.

Comment: I am really sorry man. It's something I would not like to disclose :(... you can call me shy. I hope I didn't offend you by this.

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
       emailid + '' + type LIKE 'test1234EXT' 
       OR emailid LIKE 'test1234EXT'  
       OR type LIKE 'test1234EXT'
```

Check this in SQLFiddler [**Fiddler**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae097/2)

Comment: not working...the user may type either test1234 or ext or both test234ext so it shud be flexible

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.